# Why when I use TextUtils to control input on searchView onBackPressed method returns null in android?

Tags: android, listview

I have a searchView and a Listview. I have the following method to filter my Listview

```
@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(query)) {
        listAdapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), readList (getBaseContext(),"Categories"), FinalMap);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    } else {
        listAdapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), readList (getBaseContext(),"Categories"), FinalMap);
        listAdapter.filterData(query);
        expandableListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    }
    return true;
}
```

My problem starts when I go to the next activity and press Back, my FinalMap becomes null so the adapter is not working.

**When I comment onQueryTextChange code, onBackPressed method works fine!**

At the same time I removed searchView focus but it seems its not causing the problem.

**Update:**

```
 @Override
 public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(query)) 
{
    return false;
} else {
    listAdapter = new CustomExpandableListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), readList (getBaseContext(),"Categories"), FinalMap);
    listAdapter.filterData(query);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
 return true;
}

}
```

Now with this change I can get back but its not working if I type and search and find something from list open it and try to go back

How to deal with such a problem?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Can you put the complete codes of your activity?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it is right approach but I added in my adapter and in my filtermethod the following which re builts my JSONObject and my Details list

```
db = new SQLiteHandler(context);
    SavedResponse mysavedresponse = new SavedResponse();
    JSONObject j = null;
    JSONArray result = null;
    //Get my initial response saved in sqlite
    mysavedresponse = db.getMySavedResponse();
    String MyResponse = mysavedresponse.getSavedresponse();

    try {
        j = new JSONObject(MyResponse);
        //Storing the Array of JSON String to our JSON Array
        result = j.getJSONArray(AppConfig.JSON_ARRAY_LIST);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    expListDetail = AdapterGetUserOffers(result);
```